# Many tables on one page

Tags: tables

I have 8 table in the document. I want to show them on one page. I am using 2 column ACM format. However, right now they are automatically placed as 3 (left column) and 5 (right column). How can I do 4 and 4?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: is there space for all four tables in the left-hand column?  (please measure carefully.)  if it's clear that there *is* space, the answer will be different than if they would be "tight".

Comment: Yes, there is enough space, so that 4 tables can fit into one column.

Comment: what document class is involved?  ("2 column acm format" isn't specific enough.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code:

```
\hbox to\hsize{%
   \vtop{\hrule height0pt
         ... table 1 ...
         ... table 2 ...
         ... table 3 ...
         ... table 4 ...        
   }\hss     
   \vtop{\hrule height0pt 
         ... table 5 ...
         ... table 6 ...
         ... table 7 ...
         ... table 8 ...
   }%  
}
```

I suppose that each table is a single box (it is irrelevant how it is created).

Answer (score 1):

I gather that you currently have eight separate `table` environments, each one containing exactly one `tabular` environment (plus `\caption` and `\label`). To exploit the fact that LaTeX won't break floats across pages, you could create just two `table` environments, each one containing *four* `tabular` environments (plus associated `\caption`s and `\label`s).

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[textheight=3in]{geometry} % just for this example
\usepackage[skip=3pt]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t!]
\caption{First of eight} \label{tab:1}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\caption{Second of eight} \label{tab:2}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\caption{Third of eight} \label{tab:3}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\caption{Fourth of eight} \label{tab:4}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[t!]
\caption{Fifth of eight} \label{tab:5}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\caption{Sixth of eight} \label{tab:6}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\caption{Seventh of eight} \label{tab:7}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\caption{Eighth of eight} \label{tab:8}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use a `table*` environment, where as many captions as one wants can be used.

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-2013} % or other ACM template

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example, provides filler nonsense text

\begin{document}

\title{A paper}
\author{A. Uthor}
\maketitle

\lipsum

\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
\caption{First of eight} \label{tab:1}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
\caption{Second of eight} \label{tab:2}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
\caption{Third of eight} \label{tab:3}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
\caption{Fourth of eight} \label{tab:4}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
\caption{Fifth of eight} \label{tab:5}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
\caption{Sixth of eight} \label{tab:6}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
\caption{Seventh of eight} \label{tab:7}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
\caption{Eighth of eight} \label{tab:8}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{table*}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]